# Sculpt not showing up in rendered view

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, sculpting

Good day to all. I use Blender 2.79, and I had just finished sculpting some details on a face. So, I decided to view how my (blender) face would look in rendered mode. But, when I switched to rendered mode, it only displayed a plain UV Sphere!

[image: Sculpt Mode]

[image: Rendered Preview Mode]

Sculpt Mode
Rendered Preview Mode

Thank you to all!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your mode is set to sculpt. Change your preview/render to object mode instead of sculpt mode.